# How to debug an Heroku app, since logs don't help att all?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs app on heroku for the first time, but I'm stuck at the command "heroku open" since it gives me an application error and no information as to where it crashed. The app runs locally without problem.
How would you proceed to debug this?
Thanks for your advice and time.

Answer (score 11):

If running `heroku local` does not help, run a remote shell:
`heroku run -a <your app name> /bin/bash`, and there run `npm start` to see the logs and debug the issue on the Heroku server.

Comment: After `npm start` it's auto exist any way to keep running via remote shell

Comment: I like this answer the most because it also shows an alternative if you don't have Linux or Mac. For Windows users, the `heroku local` won't work.

Answer (score 5):

When running your app "locally", have you tried running `heroku local`?  This runs the app through Heroku, but on local server.